# Capturing video with raspberry using opencv+picamera stream IO

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm using the Raspberry to simply show a video (just this for now). To do this i have to use opencv (cv2). I tried many solution, but now i want to capture the video using the Picamera library.
I'll show you my code:

```
import io
import time
import picamera
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create the in-memory stream
stream = io.BytesIO()
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    while True:
        camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')
        # Construct a numpy array from the stream
        data = np.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)
        # "Decode" the image from the array, preserving colour
        image = cv2.imdecode(data, 1)
        cv2.imshow('frame', image)
```

It's really simple as you can see, but it doesn't work. Actually it doesn't evev open the window.
I would like to reproduce the behavior of the next one, which works perfectly:

```
#import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any idea ?

Comment: It seems that cv2.imshow('frame', image) is not working properly.

Comment: you forgot the cv2.waitKey() line. it won't work without.

Comment: Really? ... Why? ... Isn't cv2.waitKey() just about getting commands from the keyboard ?

Comment: definitely not. it contains the window's messageloop and does the actual blitting

Comment: Now it opens the window, but it's actually empty. Have i forgot anything ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this blog posting](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/). It has the code to get this working:

```
# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera)

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# grab an image from the camera
camera.capture(rawCapture, format="bgr")
image = rawCapture.array

# display the image on screen and wait for a keypress
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

A bit further down there is an example with capturing images continually.

```
# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array

    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Comment: I have the pretty weird behaviour that your first solution would work and the second one only produces black frames pn my Raspi 3. Anybody any idea about what the problem could be here?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

to ensure you have the video for linux drivers

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem where the camera output was working but the video stream was always black. It turns out that it's a picamera version issue. Installing 1.10 worked for me without any other deviations from the demo code:

```
pip install 'picamera[array]'== 1.10
```

Answer (score 0):

First, cv2.waitKey() needs to be added to the following line of cv2.imshow('frame', image). Then, stream.seek(0); stream.truncate(); need to be added to the end of the loop, otherwise the image will not change.